# What is ${} maven syntax for dependency?

Tags: maven

For example using logback dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does `<version>${logback.version}</version>` download the latest version of the dependency ?

Comment: Simply answer to this No.. It will download the version which is defined by the value of the property...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a maven property as defined in the properties section - see https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties for more details.

In this example you can set the `logback.version` property to e.g. `3.5.1` using the following syntax: -

```
<properties>
    <logback.version>3.5.1<logback.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

bobmarksie, absolutely right, but there is note, using latest version is not good:

> Internally, Maven 2.x used the special version markers RELEASE and
>   LATEST to support automatic plugin version resolution. These
>   metaversions were also recognized in the  element for a
>    declaration. For the sake of reproducible builds, Maven 3.x
>   no longer supports usage of these metaversions in the POM. As a
>   result, users will need to replace occurrences of these metaversions
>   with a concrete version.

[link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution)